# Continuous monotone functions on $[a,b]$ are homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, inverse-function, monotone-functions

I am reading this book in analysis. I want to check if my proof is correct.

> Let $a < b$ be real numbers, and $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is both continuous and strictly monotone increasing. Then $f$ is a bijection from $[a,b]$ to $[f(a),f(b)]$, and the inverse $f^{-1} : [f(a),f(b)] \rightarrow [a,b]$ is continuous and strictly monotone.

Attempt:

Assume $f^{-1}$ isn't continuous. Then there exists a sequence $(y_n)_{n}$ such that $y_n$ converges to $y_0$, but $x_n = f^{-1}(y_n)$ doesn't converge to $x_0 = f^{-1}(y_0)$. By Heine Borel we have that the sequence $x_n$ has convergent subsequence $x_{n_j}$ that converges to $x_0^{\prime}$. By uniqueness of limits and continuity we must have $f(x_0^{\prime}) = y_0$. $f(x_0^{\prime}) = y_0 = f(x_0)$. It follows that $x_0^{\prime} = x_0$. I am not sure what to do from here.

Edit: I think it is from construction of the $x_i$ sequence, that all of its subsequence are convergent to $x_0$.

I think my proof works though Heine-Borel is heavy machinery to use here. I wonder if you can get without Heine-Borel

Comment: Hint: you can prove that if $f$ is defined on an interval and strictly monotone, then $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: I did prove that.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678389/how-do-we-prove-that-strictly-monotone-continuous-functions-admit-strictly-monot)

Comment: @CipherCode, you seem to require $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much. Though I would like to check my own proof attempt.

Comment: @Alexey Assumption f is continuous.

Comment: @CipherCode, in my comment -- no.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check the proof in your comment!